# Variable gets not substituted by its value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to insert data from table AnswerSets

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Q1    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Q2    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Q3    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
[...]
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

to T_ANSWER_SET.

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| U_ID   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Q_ID   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ANSWER | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Therefor I use the following query in a loop in a procedure:

```
INSERT INTO T_ANSWER_SET (U_ID, Q_ID, ANSWER)
SELECT i, j, (SELECT c FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = i);
```

`i`, `j` are integers and are used are incremented in a loop. `c` is a name of a column (like 'Q10') of AnswerSets from which I want the data. But I get always this:

```
+------+------+--------+
| U_ID | Q_ID | ANSWER |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    1 |      0 |
|    1 |    2 |      0 |
|    1 |    3 |      0 |
[...]
+------+------+--------+
```

What I want the query to do for i =3, j = 10 and c = 'Q10':

```
INSERT INTO T_ANSWER_SET (U_ID, Q_ID, ANSWER)
SELECT 3, 10, (SELECT Q10 FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = 3);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This makes very little sense as of now. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to include all necessary information, including the table definition for both of those tables.

Comment: hope it helps you to understand what my problem is

Comment: All those columns are of integer type, so it is unlikely that anything gets casted to 0 accidentially here. `SELECT Q10 FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = 3` gives you what result?

Comment: `> select Q10 from AnswerSets where Id = 3;`
+------+
 | Q10  |
+------+
 |    3 |
+------+

Comment: I don’t know what that is supposed to mean. You selected one column from a single row only, so you should only be getting one single value.

Comment: it was the output from the commandline but I could not make a newline in a comment. I get the value 3

Comment: First of all, I would make that into one select statement: `SELECT 3, 10, Q10 FROM AnswerSets WHERE Id = 3` - as long as the record in AnswerSets with Id = 3 exists, that will give you all three values in one go. (And it will return an empty result, so nothing will be inserted at all, if that record did not exist. So you could call that an additional measure against wrong data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PREPARE Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/prepare-statement/):

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SET @`i` := 3,
    ->     @`j` := 1,
    ->     @`c` := '`Q10`';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @`stmt` := CONCAT('
    '> INSERT INTO `T_ANSWER_SET` (`U_ID`, `Q_ID`, `ANSWER`)
    '> SELECT ', @`i`, ', ', @`j`, ', (SELECT ', @`c`, '
    '>                                 FROM `AnswerSets`
    '>                                 WHERE `Id` = ', @`i`, ')
    '> ');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @`stmt`;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @`stmt`                                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 
INSERT INTO `T_ANSWER_SET` (`U_ID`, `Q_ID`, `ANSWER`)
SELECT 3, 1, (SELECT `Q10`
              FROM `AnswerSets`
              WHERE `Id` = 3)
 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> -- PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`stmt`;
MariaDB [(none)]> -- EXECUTE `stmt`;
MariaDB [(none)]> -- DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```